# How to encode cookie with javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, cookies

I am working on an online shop together with my friend. He set a cookie for me with PHP with the amount of added products to the Cart. The cookie is called "cart", and the variable with the amount of the products is called "items".

And I have to read the cookie and get the value of "cart" back with javascript and print it in the HTML document, but I have no Idea how to use it, can you please help me? I have never worked with cookies or JSON before, but I think it should be done with JSON, can you please explain it to me how it works?

when I do : `console.log(document.cookie);`

I receive something like this: `cart=%7B%22items%22%3A%7B%228%22%3A1%7D%7D;`

And I have no idea how to encode it.

Thank you

Comment: How was the cookie encoded in PHP?

Comment: That's just URL encoded.

Comment: You're talking about DEcoding, not ENcoding. Pls change the title.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is the URL encoded equivalent of `{"items":{"8":1}}` which is the JSON string you want.

All you have to do is decode it and parse the JSON:

```
var cart = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(document.cookie.cart));
```

Then logging cart should give you an object with an 'items' property that you can access as needed.

EDIT:

As an example, here's a way to iterate through the items and determine the total number of items and the total of all their quantities.

```
var items_total = 0,
    quantity_total = 0;
for (var prop in cart.items) {
    items_total += 1;
    quantity_total += cart.items[prop];
}

console.log("Total Items: " + items_total);
console.log("Total Quantities: " + quantity_total);
```

Comment: How should I implement it? How can I the value save in a variable?

Comment: At this point you have an object `cart` that has an object `items` within it. The items object has a property named `8` with a value of `1` (item id 8, with a quantity of 1? - I'm guessing here).

You could access this with `cart.items["8"]`, but you'll likely want to work through that items object to determine what you want to display. You can iterate through it and find out how many items there are, or find out how many of each item, or any number of other things.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just need to decode it, then you will want to parse/eval it to get a workable object:

```
var obj, decoded = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie.cart);
if(window.JSON && JSON.parse){
  obj = JSON.parse(decoded);
} else {
  eval('obj = ' + decoded);
}
// obj == {"items":{"8":1}};
```