# Jquery cookie delete with JS-Cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies

I'm saving some ids into a single cookie array. The cookie looks like: id1%id2%id3.

Is there any way I can delete only of the ids in the cookie, without having to delete the whole cookie?

For example, I want to delete 'id1', the cookie will now store id2%id3. I don't want to make a separate cookie for each data.

P.S. I'm using JS-Cookie to store the cookies.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9928472/2686143

Comment: This generates me id1,id2,id3... and I asked how to delete part of it.

Comment: `var newValue = oldValue.replace("id1%", "");` and make sure the cookie string always ends with a `%`, e.g. `id1%id2%id3%`

Comment: That worked, please post it as an answer so I can approve it :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the substring from the cookie value, like this:

```
var newValue = oldValue.replace("id1%", "");
```

To have this work for the final component, make sure the cookie string always ends with a `%`, e.g. `id1%id2%id3%`